# How to disable most visited tabs in Google Chrome on Mac?

Tags: mac, google-chrome

I have previously been able to disable the new tab most visited thumbnails by disabling the "Enable Instant Extended API" in the chrome://flags/.  This isn't an option on Chrome 33.0.1750.117 on OSX 10.9.

Any way to disable this again?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide/disable the Most Visited thumbnails, the "Empty New Tab Page" extension is not the best solution because then you'll also be missing all other elements (mainly the search bar, Google logo and the bookmarks bar).

To hide the Most Visited thumbnails only, use the [Hide Most Visited Pages Reloaded](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hide-most-visited-pages-r/dhphmpoekpoecdbjeionimpiceigkeil?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) extension. The nice thing about this extension is that it allows you to show or hide each element of the Home/New Tab page to your taste.

Comment: Highly recommended ;)

Answer (score 0):

That option was deprecated. Install the "Empty New Tab Page" extension on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly create a directory newtab (or sumptin)

Inside it you are going to create a file called

manifest.json - in it

```
{ 
"manifest_version": 2, 
"name": "StupidBoxes", 
"version": "1.0", 
"description": "Improving GOOGLE", 
"chrome_url_overrides" : { 
"newtab": "newtab.html" 
} 
}
```

That's mine, you get the idea.

then create your own newtab.html. Here is mine

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Addinall's Override TAB Page</title>

<style>
body {
background-image: url('images/cerebus-newtab.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: cover;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

You can stick whatever you fancy in your newtab page now. The omnibar up the top still does a Google search.

Then go to Extensions. Load unpacked extensions in Developer mode, and you are up and away!